# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Script but class is loaded...?

Tags: java, shell, groovy

I have a problem with trying to make a shell in groovy. I am using groovy 3.0.9 and am compiling it with my jar.

The code in question:

```java
public class GrPlayerShell extends PlayerShell {
    private final Groovysh groovysh;
    private final PrintStream out;
    private final PrintStream err;
    protected GrPlayerShell(UUID uuid) {
        super(uuid, GrShell.getInstance());
        out = new PrintStream(new PlayerStream(uuid, false));
        err = new PrintStream(new PlayerStream(uuid, true));
        this.groovysh = new Groovysh(new IO(
                new InputStream() {
                    @Override
                    public int read() throws IOException {
                        throw new IOException("Not implemented");
                    }
                },
                out,
                err));
    }

    @Override
    public void doExecute(String command) {
        execute(command);
    }

    @Override
    public Result execute(String command) {
        if (command == null || command.isEmpty()) {
            return Result.EMPTY;
        }
        Object result = groovysh.execute(command); // FIXME: 12/26/21 NoClassDefFoundError: groovy.lang.Script
        return new Result(String.valueOf(result));
    }
}
```

(also [here](https://github.com/True-cc/ServerScripter/blob/master/Groovy/src/main/java/uwu/smsgamer/serverscripter/groovy/shell/GrPlayerShell.java#L44))

The `doExecute` and `execute` are running in a different thread to prevent the shell from pausing everything if the shell takes a while to execute (for example a `while (true) {}`).

This jar also gets loaded dynamically in runtime.

I have tested with java 8 and 17, yet both give exactly the same result.

Just encase the error message is of any importance:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during instruction selection: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Script

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Script
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:976)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:671)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:635)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:526)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:538)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:570)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:76)
    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Evaluator$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:204)
    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.groovy.shell.GrPlayerShell.execute(GrPlayerShell.java:67)
    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.groovy.shell.GrPlayerShell.doExecute(GrPlayerShell.java:58)
    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.shell.PlayerShell$1.run(PlayerShell.java:86)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Script
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$400(GroovyClassLoader.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.createClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:700)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.onClassNode(GroovyClassLoader.java:717)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$ClassCollector.call(GroovyClassLoader.java:721)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$3.lambda$call$0(CompilationUnit.java:806)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$3.call(CompilationUnit.java:806)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:942)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:869)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:979)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:967)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:607)
    ... 36 more

1 error

[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:295)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addException(ErrorCollector.java:143)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:976)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:671)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:635)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:526)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:538)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:570)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$parse$0.call(Unknown Source)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:76)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Evaluator$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:204)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.groovy.shell.GrPlayerShell.execute(GrPlayerShell.java:67)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.groovy.shell.GrPlayerShell.doExecute(GrPlayerShell.java:58)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at uwu.smsgamer.serverscripter.shell.PlayerShell$1.run(PlayerShell.java:86)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
[09:49:47 WARN]:    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I have no idea why this might be happening because I put a `Class.forName("groovy.lang.Script")` before and even made my own class that extends that script class and they both work just fine. Why groovy is complaining that its own script class don't exist, I have 0 idea why.

Pliz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a guess.

if you are not specifying class loader for groovysh by default it takes `Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader`

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-groovysh/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/Groovysh.groovy#L122

so, at the moment of execution `currentThread().contextClassLoader` differs from classloader where it's successful for your test `Class.forName("groovy.lang.Script")`

check that groovy libraries accessible for thread context classloader or change classloader when creating groovish object.

check that you have all groovy dependencies for runtime